# SQL Server Output query to UTF8 instead of UTF16

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, utf-8, utf-16

I have been trying to provide data to a JSON web service with the some data from a SQL query. The problem I have is that the data in stored as UTF16 in the SQL Server database and I have to provide it to the web service as UTF8.

I want to use my SQL query to transform the data when the SQL query runs. I have been reading various forums and get the impression that there isn't a particularly easy way to do the conversion.

For example I have names such as ÖSTLUND, which is valid Unicode/Windows code page 1253 as far as I understand.

Am I correct in thinking that UFT8 is more like Windows code page 1252?

I have tried doing various versions of Cast and Collate but am struggling to find which way would give me the best answer.

```
    (cast(SURNAME as varchar(100)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS)
```

or

```
    (cast(SURNANE as varchar(100)) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS_SC)
```

Has anyone got any suggestions how best to do this? Is Cast and Collate the way to do this?

**UPDATE:**

The application is an old one that is written in Uniface. The application server is running the SQL script in response to database field change. It then populates the payload of the web service post with the SQL output. The output of the SQL is made to conform to JSON for the web service.

Comment: I doubt it's possible, `sql-server` doesn't support UTF8. Maybe with CLR...

Comment: I'd do the needed coversions in your Webservice layer if at all possible. UTF-8 is not Codepage 1252

Comment: Thanks Alan, unfortuantley the web service linked to the DB is fairly dumb, it just posts the messages outwards rather than doing any processing so I need to transform the characters before it gets to the web service.

Comment: And how is the web service doing the query now to get data from the database? The conversion needs to be done where that communication is taking place.

Comment: The application is an old one that is written in Uniface. The application server is runing the SQL script in response to database field change. It then populates the payload of the webservice post with the SQL output. The output of the SQL is made to conform to JSON for the webservice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Unicode is the ability to represent all characters and not need Code Pages. UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32 are all Unicode and all represent all Unicode characters (that are currently mapped, of course).

Regarding this particular issue, SQL Server, just like Windows and .NET, really only works with UTF-16 (Little Endian) in terms of Unicode data. If you want strings in UTF-8, then you would encode them as UTF-8 after getting the data back from SQL Server in the result set, as you are packaging it up into the JSON format. So it sounds like it will have to be done in "Uniface".

Also, regarding the two `CAST` statements in the Question, they effectively do the same thing since both are using Latin1 locale/LCID which maps to Code Page 1252 for `VARCHAR` data.